# Data won't load firebase.google.com database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to save and load the username of my players to a firebase database, but for some reason it's not working. The username is null when I use alerts to debug it. I initialize firebase in a  tag in my html file. Here is my code for username saving and loading. Saving works, but not loading:

```
var signedIn = false;
var player;
var isAnonymous;
var userID;

var username = null;

window.onload = function() {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        //var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            player = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            signedIn = true;
            isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
            userID = user.uid;
            refreshUsername();
        } else {
            // No user is signed in.
            signedIn = false;
            window.location.href = "index.html";
        }
    });
}

function refreshUsername() {
    if (username != null && username != "") {
        updateUsername();
        document.getElementById("username-text").innerHTML += username;
    } else {
        updateUsername();
        alert("old Not working: " + username);
        var newName = getRandomName();
        document.getElementById("username-text").innerHTML += newName;
        saveUsername(newName);
        username = newName;
        alert("Not working: " + username);
    }
}

function saveUsername(name) {
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + userID).set({
        username: name
    });
}

function updateUsername() {
    /*firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userID).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        username = snapshot.val().username;
    });*/
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + userID).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        username = snapshot.val().username;
    });
}
```

Comment: Add error handlers to your listeners and see what they output?

Comment: @kato I did, inside the method it works, but it returns null

Comment: there are no error handlers on the once method or set method.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working. The firebase stuff was taking so long that the rest of the code was finished before the username was updated. I fix it by using callbacks. Here is my working code:

```
var signedIn = false;
var player;
var isAnonymous;
var userID;

var username = null;

window.onload = function() {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        //var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            player = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            signedIn = true;
            isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
            userID = user.uid;
            refreshUsername();
        } else {
            // No user is signed in.
            signedIn = false;
            window.location.href = "index.html";
        }
    });
}

function refreshUsername() {
    document.getElementById("username-text").innerHTML = "Username: " + "Loading...";
    updateUsername(function() {
        if (username != null) {
            document.getElementById("username-text").innerHTML = "Username: " + username;
        } else {
            randomUsername();
        }
    });   
}

function saveUsername(name) {
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + userID).set({
        username: name
    });                         
}

function updateUsername(_callback) {
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + userID).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        username = snapshot.val().username;
        _callback();
    });
}
```